# Visual Studio Hide selected files

Tags: visual-studio, hide, solution

In the solution explorer I have a large number of .dlls that I would rather not have shown in the Solution Explorer - just to tidy up the display and allow me to focus on the files I need to.

Q) Is there a way to hide selected files from displaying in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: where are they located? Can you put them all in a new folder and just minimize that folder?

Comment: They are located in the root of the project and can't be moved to a folder - at least not that I have discovered so far. They belong to a third party application that I run as a child process.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the references of the dlls that you want to move.
Create a new folder in your project and put all those dlls into that new folder (from Windows explorer). Then by right clicking on them in VS, select Include In Project to be sure that they are included. (If they are included successfully, Exclude From Project should be written when you right click.)

Then if you add them as reference (by right clicking References>Add) again from that new folder, you should be able to use these dlls now without any problems.

Now you can minimize the new folder to tidy up the display.